# In Google Adwords the impressions and clicks are not broken out according to keyword

Tags: google, analytics, google-ads

Even though I have thousands of impressions and a few dozen clicks, there is no detail in the AdWords interface about the keywords.

In other words, I would like to know which clicks and impressions came from which keywords. This way I can make better decisions as to which keywords I should use!

[image]

Comment: I can't really be sure by looking only at that, but take a look at your campaign settings and find out if display networks is activated as the ads may show on sites other than google, not triggering keywords, therefore no clicks.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to see what words the user used to trigger your ads. Under the keywords tab, use the checkbox to select the keyword, then press details and click "search terms" "selected"[image: Adwords search term]

Answer (score 0):

To get to the keywords you have to click on the campaign and then the ad group.   It looks like you are on the Campaign level and just need to dive deeper.

Once you get down to that level, it is broken out by keyword with a header like this:

[image: ad group showing keywords]